# How to get all documents after some specific document REST Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm investigating using Firestore in my app. Currently I try to understand is it possible to get documents that start from some specific item. I have next task: The app load all documents that currently in database. After some time the app want to download newest documents that weren't downloaded yet. I see that every document has uniq id that creates by Firestore system and I want to use it to get all document after item with specific id.
Currently I use next link
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{myawesome_project}/databases/(default)/documents/test
and I see next result

```
{
    "documents": [
    {
        "name": "projects/{myawesome_project}/databases/(default)/documents/test/MWmpU4j2tx9GwazVJZGe",
        "fields": {
        "f3": {
        "integerValue": "3"
    },
        "f2": {
        "stringValue": "v2"
    },
        "f1": {
        "stringValue": "v11"
    }
    },
        "createTime": "2018-03-07T22:51:33.578626Z",
        "updateTime": "2018-03-07T23:02:18.346358Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "projects/{myawesome_project}/databases/(default)/documents/test/TzKJzpodgolviEIVzmq0",
        "fields": {
        "f3": {
        "integerValue": "1"
    },
        "f2": {
        "stringValue": "v2"
    },
        "f1": {
        "stringValue": "v1"
    }
    },
        "createTime": "2018-03-07T22:51:07.098609Z",
        "updateTime": "2018-03-07T23:02:28.964951Z"
    },
    {
        "name": "projects/{myawesome_project}/databases/(default)/documents/test/xuGRH1NSdpiri3uYaHnl",
        "fields": {
        "f1": {
        "stringValue": "v12"
    },
        "f3": {
        "integerValue": "2"
    },
        "f2": {
        "stringValue": "v22"
    }
    },
        "createTime": "2018-03-07T22:51:53.276245Z",
        "updateTime": "2018-03-07T23:01:57.788212Z"
    }
    ]
}
```

Let's say the app downloaded everything by document TzKJzpodgolviEIVzmq0(second one), and in next request I want to get all data from this point. I tried use orderBy=name, but it doesn't work
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{myawesome_project}/databases/(default)/documents/test?orderBy=name&startAt=TzKJzpodgolviEIVzmq0
Does anyone know how to get documents from some specific document